Étymologie de « snober »
Le verbe snober semble correspondre quasi-parfaitement au sens de snub en anglais.
L'Oxford Dictionary of English donne la définition "rebuff, ignore or spurn didainfully" et les exemples suivants.

He snubbed faculty members and students alike.


They snubbed his invitation to a meeting of foreign ministers.

Le Petit Robert donne la définition "traiter (qqn) de haut, le mépriser, l'éviter par snobisme" et les exemples suivants.

Il « ne cherchait pas à cacher que Charlus les snobait ».


Snober une réunion.

D'autre part l'approximation attendue en français de la prononciation de snub serait [snɔb].
Les ouvrages de référence nous disent pourtant que le verbe snober vient de snob par dérivation. Je n'en ai vu aucun qui mentionne une hypothèse snub, ne serait-ce que pour la rejeter.
Ma question est de savoir s'il y a une base solide pour affirmer que la source de snober est bien snob et non snub.
Pour moi, il n'y a pas de doute que les francophones font un lien mental entre snober et snob, mais ce lien-là aurait pu venir a posteriori. C'est-à-dire que je propose que snober serait venu de snub avec une influence de snob sur l'orthographe et dans une certaine mesure le sens.
Edit. Ayant lu maintenant la première attestation de snober, chez Proust, je suis disposé à croire que son usage du mot provient directement de snob.

La persévérance [...] de Mme de Villebon à snober Mme G. [...] ne fut pas tout à fait inutile. Aux yeux de Mme G., elle doua Mme de Villebon d’un prestige tel [...] que, quand la fille de Mme G. [...] fut à marier, on s'étonna de lui voir refuser tous les ducs. C'est que sa mère [...] ne souhaitait véritablement qu'un mari pour sa fille : un fils Villebon.

Le Dictionnaire historique de la langue française, suggéré dans un commentaire par @None, dit ceci:

SNOBER v. tr. semble avoir été lancé (1921) par Proust (ou dans son milieu) au sens de « traiter qqn de haut » ; le verbe s'est répandu (v. 1960) au sens de « dédaigner », sans référence obligée au snobisme mondain.

C'est donc le sens qui s'est répandu vers 1960 qui se rapproche du verbe snub en anglais et qui aurait pu être influencé par celui-ci.

Voir TLFi snober

@Toto Oui, le TLFI indique que snober vient de snob. Mais sur quelle base peut-il l'affirmer? La coïncidence exacte avec le sens de snub me semble très improbable.

Il y a tout un passage traitant de l'étymologie.

@Toto J'ai consulté la source de la première attestation, Guermantes de Proust. En effet, snober ne semble pas y avoir le sens "éviter", et un lien fort avec snob est vraisemblable. Peut-être faudrait-il que je révise mon hypothèse en disant que "snober" aurait acquis le sens "éviter par snobisme" (le sens (b)) par la suite sous l'influence de snub.

Le TLF est sérieux et toutes les sources concordent (Dictionnaire historique de la langue française, Dictionnaire culturel en langue française) snober vient  snob, emprunt à l'anglais, c'est le livre de Thackeray qui lui a donné son sens actuel (1848), introduit en français en 1875. En anglais il n'y a aucun rapport entre les étymologies de snob et snub.

@None Vous avez mal compris ma question. Il va de soi que le mot snob en français vient de snob en anglais. Ce qui ne va pas de soi pour moi, c'est que snober, en particulier son sens "éviter", n'ait aucun rapport avec snub. Les suorces disent en effet que snober provient de snob par dérivation. C'est exactement ce que j'ai dit dans ma question. Ma question ne porte pas sur ce que les sources disent, mais sur le fondement de cette affirmation, et en particulier que snober n'ait aucun rapport avec snub. Je suis bien d'accord que snob et snub sont sans rapport en anglais.

Le fondement se sont les sources et les sources s'appuient sur l'étymologie. Par ailleurs dire que « l'approximation attendue en français de la prononciation de snub serait [snɔb] » est très personnel. Un français qui lit l'anglais mais ne sait pas le prononcer dirait spontanément [snyb], on est dans la spéculation et pas dans les faits. Par contre  le rapprochement phonétique a déjà été fait par des anglophones.

@دولةفلسطين Tous les locuteurs d'une langue n'ont pas besoin de connaître un mot étranger pour que ce mot soit emprunté. Pour la question concernant, snob et snub, je suis convaincu qu'ils n'ont aucun absolument aucun rapport entre eux en anglais. Ce que je pense maintenant (voir l'edit que j'ai fait), c'est que le français a emprunté le mot snob à l'anglais (snob) au 19e siècle. Il a formé plusieurs dérivés, snobisme, snobinard, etc., et snober dans les années 1920. Initialement, snober n'avait pas le sens éviter de parler à (qqn), de rencontrer (qqn) qu'il a acquis...

@دولةفلسطين dans les années 1960. Et c'est ce sens-là qui montre un parallélisme tel avec le sens de snub en anglais, que je soupçonne une influence de snub.

@None Snob et snub ont des prononciations totalement distinctes pour les anglophones. Par contre, le mot club, qui rime avec snub en anglais, a la prononciation [klœb], qui est proche de [snɔb]. Je suis parfaitement d'accord que parfois un emprunt étranger est lu suivant son orthographe, mais parfois un mot peut être emprunté à partir de sa forme orale. Surtout qu'ici, je pense qu'en entendant snub en anglais, les francophones auraient pu faire un faux rapprochement avec snob.

Tout à fait hors sujet sur FL mais en rapport avec la question Of Snubs and Snobs. Et je viens d'apprendre que si c'est bien Thackeray qui aidé à répandre le mot snob, en fait c'est un Canadien qui a forgé sons sens moderne...

« totalement distinctes » absolutely not! And I'm not the only one to say so, "They sound so similar, and they both carry meanings of rudeness and disrespect. The meaning difference conveyed by that one changed vowel suggests...". Just follow link in my previous comment for complete quote.

Évidemment, dans mon commentaire,  [klœb] et [snɔb] faisaient référence aux prononciations françaises.

@None Dans un accent nord-américain, la voyelle de snob est longue et celle de snub brève. Les voyelles sont difficiles à confondre. Il faudrait voir pour les régions d'Angelerre, mais dans le sud-est, snob a une voyelle postérieure et snub une voyelle antérieure.

@دولةفلسطين Exactly. If you find phonesthemes an interesting case of study you might be interested in Didier Bottineau. Some of his papers are in open access. e.g.
